# javascript toggle button dont work

Tags: javascript, button, toggle

```
<input tyoe="button" onclick="toggle()" value="Show Spoilers" />
<div id="spoilers" style="display: none;">Some spoilers</div>
<script>
function toggle(){
   var div = document.getElementById("spoilers");
   if(div.style.display = "none"){
      div.style.display = "block";
   } else {
      div.style.display = "none";
   }
}
</script>
```

it worked to show, but cannot hide the div. So it worked only for showing not for hiding it? Any thing i did wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot an equal (=) in your if

```
function toggle()
{
    var div = document.getElementById("spoilers");
    if(div.style.display === "none"){
        div.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        div.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/90Lw12cf/

Answer (score 2):

```
function toggle () {
    var div = document.getElementById('spoilers');

    div.style.display = div.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, one should also explain how and why this code helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you got some spoilerS with a "s" you should use a class instead of an ID.

Then I recommend not to do it directly with JavaScript but to add a class hidden with the css `display:none` property.

```
function toggle(){ 
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("spoilers");
    for(var i = 0; i > divs.length i++){
        if(divs[i].classList.contains("hidden")) {
            divs[i].classList.remove = "hidden";
        } else { 
            divs[i].classList.add = "hidden"; 
        }
    }  
}
```